# What is the most efficient method to iterate over a Perl array?

Tags: perl

I am reading an ordered file for which I must count by-hour, by-minute or by-second occurrences. If requested, I must print times with 0 occurrences (normalized output) or skip them (non-normalized output). The output must obviously be ordered.

I first thought using an array. When the output is non normalized, I am doing roughly the equivalent of:

```
@array[10] = 100;
@array[10000] = 10000;
```

And to print the result:

```
foreach (@array) {
  print if defined;
}
```

Is there a way to reduce iterations to only elements defined in the array? In the previous example, that would mean doing only two iterations, instead of 10000 as using `$#array` implies. Then I would also need a way to know the current array index in a loop. Does such a thing exist?

I am thinking more and more to use a hash instead. Using a hash solves my problem and also eliminates the need to convert hh:mm:ss times to index and vice-versa.

Or do you have a better solution to suggest for this simple problem?

Comment: hash is indeed what you need in this case.

Comment: When the "key" or "index" range is relatively large compared to the number of meaningful elements (ie, a sparse structure), a hash is better suited.  If the number of meaningful elements is high relative to the range of indices (a dense structure), and the cost of computing indices is low, an array can be more time efficient since it avoids the overhead of the hashing algorithm.

Comment: Question is, I think, why you use an array in the first place? Are the indexes part of your data? If not, why bother with them?

Comment: @TLP: index is time. It is part of the data.

Comment: Use a hash, or a two-dimensional array, is my advice. E.g. `push @array [ 10, 100 ]`. No sense keeping empty array elements.

Comment: I think there is a misunderstanding of my definition of normalized output. I am collecting data related to time. Data can be spread any way imaginable over 24 hours. In normalized mode, I have to print *all* timestamps with the associated counter (say 1440 lines for per-minute stats). Keeping data in a compact array is not very practical.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, use a hash. You can iterate over the ordered array of the keys of the hash if your keys sort correctly.

Comment: I settled for a solution using an array. The advantage of the hash is not obvious because my data is generally well distributed over the day. Especially when producing stats per-hour. With a hash I wouldn't need to sort keys because they represent time values. I simply have to iterate over time and print corresponding hash values. A hash would save some memory depending on situations. Maybe it would also be faster (for this problem) but I'd have to test.

Comment: Is your data regularly spaced or irregular? If it is irregular, you will end up with gaps which waste space; the more granularity you need in ability to say '0 events in this period', the more spaces you'll have. Perhaps if you give a couple of real examples it will be clearer.

Answer (score 2):

You can also remember just the pairs of numbers in an array:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my @ar = ( [  10, 100 ],
           [ 100,  99 ],
           [  12,   1 ],
           [  13,   2 ],
           [  15,   1 ],
         );

sub normalized {
    my @ar = sort { $a->[0] <=> $b->[0] } @_;
    map "@$_", @ar;
}

sub non_normalized {
    my @ar = sort { $a->[0] <=> $b->[0] } @_;
    unshift @ar, [0, 0] unless $ar[0][0] == 0;
    my @return;
    for my $i (0 .. $#ar) {
        push @return, "@{ $ar[$i] }";
        push @return, $_ . $" . 0 for 1 + $ar[$i][0] .. $ar[$i + 1][0] - 1;
    }
    return @return;
}


print join "\n", normalized(@ar), q();
print "\n";
print join "\n", non_normalized(@ar), q();
```